# Вложенные циклы python

Tags: python

Появилась задача: из словаря

> data = {29: [7,8,4], 31: [3,7,9], 21: [9,4,3]}

получить иной словарь, который содержит в себе те же самые поля, но на месте чисел в листах например [7,8,9] получить числа других полей(keys) словаря, которые содержат в своих values хотя бы одно число из values других keys. Более понятно будет видно на примере правильного ответа:

> array = {31: [21, 21, 29], 21: [29, 31, 31], 29: [21, 31]}

Я решил задачу, но меня смущает кличество вложенных циклов:

```
array = {}
for i in data:
    array[i] = []
    for k in data:
        if k != i:
            for j in data[k]:
                if j in data[i]:
                    array[i].append(k)              

print array
```

**Вопрос**, как вы избавляетесь от вложенности циклов, какие библиотеки и дополнительные методы порекомендовали бы в помощь и возможно решили бы данную задачу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
data = {
  1: [1, 2, 3],
  2: [4, 5, 6],
  3: [1, 4, 6],
}

def intersect(l1, l2):
    for item in l1:
        if item in l2:
            return True
    return False


answer = {}
for key in data:
    answer[key] = [k for k in data if intersect(data[key], data[k])]

print answer

>>>{1: [1, 3], 2: [2, 3], 3: [1, 2, 3]}
```

Разница с Вашим алгоритмом в том, что в значениях ответа не будет повторяющися значений (сорри за тавтологию).

Можно и без внешнего цикла:

```
answer = {key: [k for k in data if k != key and intersect(data[key],
          data[k])] for key in data}
```

В одну строчку без описания функции:

```
answer = {key: [k for k in data if k != key and \
          (set(data[k]) & set(data[key]))] for key in data}
```

Если нужно, можно потом удалить пустые списки:

```
for key in answer:
    if not answer[key]:
        del answer[key]
```

Comment: На самом деле, просто один цикл убран в функцию (что ИМХО правильно), а еще один в генератор списка. Если в списке ответа с ключом `i` не должно быть значения `i`  поменять `if` на `if k != key and intersect(data[key], data[k]`

Comment: Супер! Спасибо), очень развернуто!

Comment: Будьте только осторожны, мое решение не идентично Вашему. В вашем примере мой результат будет `array = {31: [21, 29], 21: [29, 31], 29: [21, 31]}` Если нужно именно столько вхождений исходного ключа, сколько есть совпадающих значений, то ИМХО сработает только Ваш алгоритм, только я бы спрятал часть вложенности в функции. Ну и остается вопрос, что будет эффективнее при больших объемах входных данных.